# ASP.NET - How to forward HttpContext user credentials from MVC app to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a solution where I have an ASP.NET MVC application, and an ASP.NET API. When someone lands on the home page of the MVC App, I am accessing the HttpContext inside the home controller to get the user's credentials, which I then use for various things. Inside the Home Controller, I also need to call my API (mentioned above), and that API also needs to access the user's credentials via HttpContext.

This works fine when I am debug this locally, and both the MVC App and API can see my credentials as [MyDomainName]/[MyUserName]. However, when running them both on my IIS Server, the MVC App can access my credentials correctly, while the API sees them as IIS AppPool/[MyAppPool], or whatever account the app pool hosting the MVC App is running as.

I understand why this happens, on the server from the API's perspective the user that sent the request is the MVC App's app pool if the API request is sent from the server-side scripts (MVC App's Home Controller). The problem is that it's a requirement that I must send these requests from the Controller (or anywhere from within the server-side C# code), I can't quite make these from the Javascript files inside the MVC App (which I know would work).

Does anyone know if there is a way to forward the credentials with an API request made from within the server-side C# code? I understand this might not be allowed for security reasons, but just want to check what is people's approach when dealing with this?

Comment: It seems to me like you are doing things the wrong way here. You should be getting user information from authentication claims, and using OAuth "on behalf of" tokens to call a secondary API on behalf of the initial user. I'd rethink your whole approach here and read a bit more about claims-based authentication as well as [the on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

Comment: Like the other comment indicates, if you use a modern identity framework, there are tokens to pass among apps. I guess yours currently uses Windows authentication, which actually requires complicated setup by your domain administrators and you to achieve impersonation and delegation.